# WINAPI question (about flickering)

Tags: winapi

I am painting an jpeg image using IPicture.
At first I load it, then if some conditions are met I draw it in the WM_Paint using IPicture::Render function. The problem is that it doesn't draw image if the window is closed by another window, and when I remove the closing window, only that image shows where the window was closing it. I used double buffering but the same problem, and 
I know that I should use InvalidateRect, But I can't Understand where to use it? Is there a special event like - you have to update your window? 
I need some place where I can use the InvalidateRect function.
Can you help me? 
Now I tryed using it in the CALLBACK WndProc in the default case of the switch. 
I just checked it (using double buffering) and the image is drawn imediatly even if there is an other window partially closing it, but I got flickering every time if I resize, move the window or move another window.

Comment: You need a lot more information in this question - what are you using (.NET, MFC, VCL?)  Why would you invalidate on every window message, as the default wndproc switch handler implies you are?  Please rewrite this whole thing to be a lot clearer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question doesn't really explain the situation very well. However:

Q: *At first I load it, then if some conditions are met I draw it in the `WM_PAINT` using `IPicture::Render` function.*

A: Always paint the picture in `WM_PAINT`. `WM_PAINT` is sent whenever the windows contents are damaged (by the window being resized, or uncovered by other windows) so you MUST paint during WM_PAINT or you will get unnpainted areas.

Q: *I know that I should use InvalidateRect, But I can't Understand where to use it? Is there a special event like*

A: Windows automatically calls InvalidateRect whenever Windows damages your windows contents (like when you uncover your window, restore your window, or resize your window). This ensures that a WM_PAINT message will be sent to your window.
You need to call InvalidateRect() whenever *you* change the contents of your window - for example when you finish loading a new image you would call InvalidateRect to get windows to send you a `WM_PAINT and the new image would be painted then.